# If a k-form vanishes in the neighborhood of p then it vanishes at p

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms, tensors, differential-operators

Let w be a k-form defined in an open set A of $\mathbb R^n$. We say that w vanishes on x if w(x) is the zero tensor.

Show that if w vanishes at each x in a neighborhood of $x_0$ then dw vanishes at $x_0$
I have no idea how to approach this question, please don't reveal the answer but provide intutive hints that will lead me to the solution. Thank you :)

Comment: Do you have any continuity requirements in your definition of $k$-form?

Comment: Hint: A function which is zero in a neighborhood of a point has all of its derivatives vanish also at that point.

Comment: yes a k-form w is an alternating tensor of class $\C^r \in L^k(T_x(R^n))$

Comment: @BrunoJoyal a zero derivative implies that the function is locally constant and hence, dw = 0 ? and also, thank you :)

Comment: also the second part of the question asks for an example where x vanishes at $x_0$ but dw exists. Is this an okay example let w = 2x$ \wedge $dx and $x_0$ = 0, then dw = 2 but w = 0 at $x_0$